# When writing F# for Fable, when should I use async and when should I use promise?

Tags: f#, fable-f#

F# with Fable provides two computation expressions for working with callback based code: `async` and `promise`.

`async` is more idomatic F#, but it is not clear to me how well it will work in the browser. Ideally I would be able to use `async` everywhere, since this gives me greater code reuse across client & server.

- What are the limitations of `async` in the browser?
- What are the limitations of `promise` on the server (e.g. dotnet core)
- Can I easily switch between the two? (e.g. to wrap `fetch` API)
- What is idomatic for Fable?

Note: I do not need to interop with any JavaScript, aside from the browser API.

Comment: This is a bit broad.  Do you have a specific, real-world use case we can chew on?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> What are the limitations of async in the browser?

When using `async` in the browser, you can't use `Async.RunSynchronously`. I think this is a limitation because JavaScript is single-threaded.

> What are the limitations of promise on the server (e.g. dotnet core)

You can't use `promise` on the server because .Net or .NetCore doesn't know this computation. When working with asynchronous code on a .Net or .NetCore server you need to use `async`.

If the server, is using `Node.js` the same limitation applied as in the browser.

> Can I easily switch between the two? (e.g. to wrap fetch API)

The fetch API has already been wrapped using promise in Fable.Fetch and Fable.Promise .

```
    promise {
        let! res = fetch "http://fable.io" []
        let! txt = res.text()
        // Access your resource here
        Browser.console.log txt
    }
```

Also by opening `Fable.Core` you can gain access to `Async.AwaitPromise` and `Async.StartAsPromise`.

> What is idiomatic for Fable?

Personally, I am using `promise` only because it's a native feature from JavaScript now and in general JavaScript library expects you to work using `promise` even if you can move between `promise` and `async`.

Comment: This is a really helpful clarification & perspective.  Thank you.  I am working through same consideration as OP, but leaning towards potentially aiming to try to use async{} just to try to keep a consistent description/syntax with my service-side which is also written in F# (Azure Functions).  I don't know if there is a performance hit or other problems as this compiles with FABLE (which will force me to readjust), but I find this common basis to be suited for my particular scenario and trying to keep as much F# paradigm as I can (for now, at-least!).